# Mapping preserves implications

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ and $T$ be sets, and let ${\phi}:S\, {\rightarrow}\,T $ be a mapping.

Let $*$ be an operation on $S$.
Let $x$ and $y$ be any elements of $S$ and let $a$ be any of the set's cancellable elements (under $*$).

Then, from the above, we have that ${\forall}x,y,a\,{\in}\,S:x\,*\,a=y\,*\,a{\implies}x=y$

From the definition of mapping this would mean that ${\phi}(x\,*\,a)={\phi}(y\,*\,a)$ and that ${\phi}(x)={\phi}(y)$.

However, my source says that not only can we deduce that:

> $$[{\phi}(x\,*\,a)={\phi}(y\,*\,a)] ∧ [{\phi}(x)={\phi}(y)]$$ but also that $$[{\phi}(x\,*\,a)={\phi}(y\,*\,a)] {\implies} [{\phi}(x)={\phi}(y)]$$

How are we justified in making a jump from $∧$ to ${\implies}$?

Comment: Suppose that $a=b$, a function $f$ relates each thing in its domain with EXACTLY one thing, so $f(a)=f(b)$ trivially. That is a relation, $f\subseteq X\times Y$ is a function when we have $[afy\wedge afz]\implies[y=z]$ then we may write $[f(a)=y]\iff[(a,y)\in f]$.

Comment: Have a read of http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Function this should correct your thinking

Answer (score 1):

Your source doesn't mean that
$$
\forall x\,\forall y\,(\phi(x*a)=\phi(y*a) \land \phi(x)=\phi(y)),\tag{$\it\text{not generally true}$}
$$
as this implies $\forall x\,\forall y\,\phi(x)=\phi(y)$, which says that $\phi$ is a constant function.

Your source means that if $x,y$ are such that $\phi(x*a)=\phi(y*a)$, then because of the implication $\implies$, it follows that $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$, and so the conjunction follows. However, the implication involving $\phi$ is not always true.

I don't understand how you arrive at your statement:

> From the definition of mapping this would mean that ${\phi}(x\,*\,a)={\phi}(y\,*\,a)$ and that ${\phi}(x)={\phi}(y)$.

This does not follow from what you've said up to that point. Counterexample to the implication and conjunction: $S=\Bbb N$, $T = \{0,1\}$, define $\phi\colon S\to T$ by:
$$
\phi(n) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if $n=0$,}\\
1 &\text{if $n>0$.} \end{cases}
$$
Let $*$ be $+$ on $\Bbb N$, and let $a=1$, so for all $m,n$, if $m+1=n+1$ then $m=n$. Note that $\phi(0+1) = \phi(1+1) = 1$; however, $\phi(0)\ne\phi(1)$. So, it's *not true* that $\forall x\,\forall y\,(\phi(x*a) = \phi(y*a) \to \phi(x)=\phi(y))$.

If $\phi$ is injective then this follows, but for an arbitrary function $\phi$ it does not.

**PS**

It turns out your 'source' is  proofwiki.org/wiki/Morphism_Property_Preserves_Cancellability. The "proof" given on that page is false. There, $S,T$ both have some algebraic structure, and $\phi$ is not just any function, but a *morphism* — it preserves the operations. For simplicity, consider just structures with just a single binary operation. The claim for left-cancellability is:
$$
\text{If $\phi\colon S=(S,*)\to T=(T,\star)$ is a morphism, $\\$ and if $\forall x\,\forall y\,(a*x = a*y \to \phi(x)=\phi(y))$, $\\$ then $\forall x\,\forall y\,(\phi(a*x) = \phi(a*y) \to \phi(x)=\phi(y))$.}\tag{false}
$$
This is not so. Let $(S,*)=(\Bbb N, +)$ be as above. Let $T=(\Bbb N, \star)$ where $\star$ is defined as follows:
$$
a\star x = \begin{cases}
x &\text{if a=0,}\\
1 &\text{if a>0.}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Let $\phi$ be defined as above. Then $\phi(0+x) = \phi(x)=0\star\phi(x) =\phi(0)\star\phi(x)$, and if $a>0$, then $\phi(a+x) = 1 = 1\star\phi(x)=\phi(a)\star\phi(x)$. So $\phi$ is a morphism.

Just as above, however, $\phi(1+1)=\phi(2)=\phi(1)=\phi(0+1)=1$, but $\phi(0)\ne\phi(1)$.

Comment: Why is there an implication? We know only that $x*a=y*a{\implies}x=y$, why does this work with their functions too?

Comment: OK rewind a bit. Given that implication that doesn't involve $\phi$, with $a$ cancellable, and given some $x,y\in S$, you *don't* know that $a*x=a*y$, or, what comes to the same thing, that $x=y$. In particular, if $x\ne y$ (if $S$ has more than one element, there are such), then  $\phi(a*x)\ne\phi(a*y)$. *However*, we can't conclude  $\phi(a*x)\ne\phi(a*y)$, unless we know more about $\phi$, for example that $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: I added a little. I'm still not clear about the context of your question. $S$ and $T$ are just any sets, and $\phi\colon S\to T$ any function?

Comment: Yes. The only rule is that $S$ must have cancellable elements.

Comment: Then see the (counter)example I added to my answer. The implication isn't true, neither is the conjunction.

Comment: So is there an error here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Morphism_Property_Preserves_Cancellability or did I misunderstand the proof there? Would the implication be preserved if we considered only such $x$ and $y$ that $x=y$?

Comment: There's an error there. See my PS. But also, you mis-stated the result: As I suspected, $S,T$ are both algebraic structures, and $\phi$ is not just any function but a morphism. // If you consider only $x,y$ such that $x=y$, then the result is just trivial, right?